# How to migrate Data in Oracle

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I have two tables where the Primary key in Table A is been referenced as Foreign key in Table B. I want to know a way to migrate these two tables from one Oracle DB to another. Please let me know the process and any assumptions if applicable.

Comment: It a simple export/import action, what problem you have faced during "migrate these two tables from one Oracle DB to another" ?

Comment: @HadiRasouli Before I do an export/import. I also wanted to know if only the schema is getting imported or the data in these tables also getting imported? If not, I believe I need to take backup of this data in temp tables and then insert in to the tables after migrating it to new database. Please confirm?

Comment: How big are the tables? Is the new DB on a different host? If so, how fast is the network connection to the new host? Will the tables be updated while they are being migrated or will they be static? If they are static how long will they be that way?

Comment: Also what version of Oracle?

Comment: @BobbyDurrett Each table has around 1Billion records. The new DB is on different host. I would say network connectivity is adequate. There will be a downtime during this migration, so there wouldn't be any updates. Version of Oracle 11G. Hope I answered your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the empty tables on the new database without indexes or constraints.

Copy the data over a link parallel nologging.

http://www.bobbydurrettdba.com/2012/06/21/fast-way-to-copy-data-into-a-table/

I would do this a partition at a time if the table is partitioned.

Create the indexes parallel 8 nologging.

Alter the indexes to whatever they are in source (noparallel logging maybe).

Create the foreign key constraint enable novalidate.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `expdp`/`impdp`(*export* & *import*, respectively) operations performed for data transfer between databases.

For your special case, just to migrate these two tables, it's enough to make related *foreign keys* `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` as :

```
ALTER TABLE TableB ALTER CONSTRAINT fk_tabB_A_col1
  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

unless you issue a commit until the end of the migration, there will raise no problem, provided the data is consistent, of course.

Comment: Doesn't include the details of the process.